# Reverse DNS lookup (`nslookup $ip`) returns name that doesn't exist

Tags: networking, dns, internet

I had previously configured a DNS entry that has now been removed.

If I run `nslookup mydomain.com`, I get the expected result:

```
Server:         xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Address:        xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx#xx

** server can't find mydomain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

But if I do a reverse lookup on the IP address that *was* assigned in the record:

```
$ nslookup xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa       name = mydomain.com.
```

Why is this happening and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  There's a separate "master" zone file on the DNS server with a PTR record that needs update or removal.